# Mostrar el contenido de un array más no los indexes

Tags: php, array

Este es mi código:

```
  <?PHP
  $tecnicos = 
  array ('pedro','david','alejandro','jesus','cristian','pablo', 'juan','adam');
  Echo "array original";
  Var_export($tecnicos);
  $seleccion = array_rand($tecnicos, 2);
  Echo "Las guardias serán en el siguiente orden: 
  ".$seleccion[0] ." - ".$seleccion[1];
  ?>
```

Y si, efectivamente me hace la selección aleatoria pero solamente me muestra el Index, clave, o el identificador del orden en el que están los valores del array y no el contenido como tal..
Por ejemplo, se muestra asi:
       `Array original`
       `Array( 0 => 'pedro', 1 => 'david', 2 => 'alejandro', 3 => 'jesus', 4 => 'cristian', 5 => 'pablo', 6 => 'juan', 7 => 'adam')`
       Las guardias serán en el siguiente orden: 2 - 3

Y también me gustaría aclarar una duda de cómo podría extender ese sorteo de las mismas variables al menos dos veces, supongo que con un `while` y un contador, pero no sé, porque ando un poquito bloqueado.

Y también me gustaría saber cómo hacer para que una vez en la selección aleatoria cuando seleccione a los dos primeros, no los seleccione nuevamente hasta que seleccione a todos los demas, es decir, cuando seleccione no pueda seleccionarlos nuevamente a hasta que se terminen de seleccionar el resto.

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Mostrar el contenido en vez del índice:

```
 echo "Las guardias serán en el siguiente orden: " .$tecnicos[$seleccion[0]] . " - " . $tecnicos[$seleccion[1]];
```

2 y 3) Repetir sin que salgan los elementos anteriores. Realiza todo el sorteo de una vez y guarda los valores:

```
$sorteo = $tecnicos; shuffle($sorteo);
$sorteo =array_chunck($sorteo, 2);
```

Ahora

`$sorteo[0]` tendrá el primer par de técnicos, `$sorteo[1]` el segundo, etc., sin que se repitan.